# pm2 process using the old system Environment Variables on resurrection

Tags: windows, environment-variables, startup, pm2, node-opcua

I have created a node application that is for subscribing to an OPC-UA server and storing the data on our s3 bucket. I am using the [node-opcua](https://node-opcua.github.io/) module for that purpose.

I am working on a Windows server via RDP and the `node-opcua` module creates some files under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp` as part of the process and uses it. I am using `pm2` to run the application and it is getting the path of those files via `TMP` and `TEMP` environment variables which are dynamically generated by the process itself.

When the Windows server restarts it delete those files and the location updates of the new file. I already have run `pm2 save` and put the `pm2 resurrect` command in the Batch file which has a shortcut in the windows startup to make sure the process automatically gets started.

The issue was that the pm2 process was resurrected but still throwing the error `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\{some_path} file not found` by the `node-opcua` process which was running through [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2). I ran `pm2 restart` manually but still didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I was thinking of it from the problem with the node-opcua module and thought about how can make it use the new system variables, but that was not in had as the process keeps making and deleting temporary files, so I need the pm2 to use the new system variable which has the updated path after system reboot and was not updating even after `pm2 restart`.

So, for updating the variables I figured out two solutions:

- Either delete the old process and initiate a new pm2 process to run that application and put it in the batch file which is being called at server reboot
- Adds `pm2 restart {name} --update-env` after `pm2 resurrect` and the system variables will be updated.